# How to use multiple inheritance and polymorphic dispatch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have the following structure and try to dispatch a method based on which method gets passed to `SeasonStats`. I have managed to create a dispatcher that initiates the specific subclass, but I don't now how to make it so that the selected method gets called. I have added expected output in the bottom.

```py
class Base:

    def __init__(self, league, season):
        self.league = league
        self.season = season


class PlayerStats(Base):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Base.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.player_id = [1, 2, 3]

    def get_player_stats(self):
        for i in player_id:
            print(i, self.league, self.season)

class TeamStats(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Base.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.team_id = [4, 5, 6]

    def get_team_stats(self):
        for i in player_id:
            print(i, self.league, self.season)

class FixtureStats(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Base.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fixture_id = [7, 8, 9]

    def get_fixture_stats(self):
        for i in player_id:
            print(i, self.league, self.season)

class SeasonStats(PlayerStats, TeamStats, FixtureStats):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('SeasonStats successfully initiate')

    def __call__(self, called_method, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(PlayerStats, called_method):
            print('True P')
            PlayerStats.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        elif hasattr(TeamStats, called_method):
            print('True T')
            TeamStats.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        elif hasattr(FixtureStats, called_method):
            print('True F')
            FixtureStats.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise(ValueError)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    stats = SeasonStats()
    stats('get_team_stats', 'EN_PR', '2019')

>>> 
    SeasonStats successfully initiate
    True T
    4 EN_PR 2019
    5 EN_PR 2019
    6 EN_PR 2019
```

Comment: That inheritance hierarchy makes no sense. `class SeasonStats(Player, Team, Fixture, League):` is saying that a SeasonStats instance is a player, a team, a fixture, *and* a league. You seem to have gotten the wrong idea about what inheritance means.

Comment: I believe that in this case composition would be better since "a Team has SeasonStats" and "SeasonStats is not a Team"! However, if you still want to go with multiple inheritance I think you need to explicitly call all the ctors in your init, for example call `Player.__init__(self)` in `SeasonStats.__init__`

Comment: Thank you for the input! To explain myself, `SeasonStats` is meant to be polymorphic, so that it can be either one of those objects depending on which method gets called.

Comment: Maybe the OP's hierarchy would make more sense with better naming of the base classes. E.g. if the base classes were called `PlayerStats`, `TeamStats`, and so on, then it could make sense for `ReasonStats` to *be* all of those (and get all the methods of the corresponding mixins).

Comment: @user4815162342 You are absolutely correct that the naming of the classes is off and the ones that you suggest represent the classes much better.

Comment: @MisterButler, you edited the definitions of base classes, but didn't change the definition of `SeasonStats` to match. Please create a **short** and **runnable** example that demonstrates the actual issue you are having.

Comment: @thank you for the input, I will create a miniture structure representing the issue

Comment: @user4815162342 added a short and runnable example that demonstrates the actual issue I'm are having

Comment: Sorry, it's still far from being obvious what you're trying to accomplish. Why are you calling `__init__` from inside `__call__`, which could get called multiple times? What is the point of `hasattr` since your class is inheriting from all the subclasses unconditionally? Why are you calling `hasattr` on *classes* which will give a fixed answer - do you understand what `hasattr` does? It is hard to give an answer to a question that doesn't specify the **problem** you are attempting to solve.

Comment: @user4815162342 The reason for calling `__init__` from inside `__call__` is because the subclasses attributes are expensive to initiate and I don't wan't to initiate them if I don't have to. The reason for the use of `hasattr` is to check which subclass that has to be initiated, since I don't want to initiate all of them and only the one that is needed.

Answer (score -2):

Problem was solved using a dispatch-map for each subclass. Even if it was not optimal since a dispatch-map had to be created for each subclass and relies on implementation rather than abstraction it is a working solution at the moment.

```py
class Base:

    def __init__(self, league, season):
        self.league = league
        self.season = season


class PlayerStats(Base):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.dispatch_map = { 'get_player_stats' : self.get_player_stats}
        Base.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.player_id = [1, 2, 3]

    def get_player_stats(self):
        for i in self.player_id:
            print(i, self.league, self.season)

class TeamStats(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.dispatch_map = { 'get_team_stats' : self.get_team_stats}
        Base.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.team_id = [4, 5, 6]

    def get_team_stats(self):
        for i in self.team_id:
            print(i, self.league, self.season)

class FixtureStats(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.dispatch_map = { 'get_fixture_stats' : self.get_fixture_stats}
        Base.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fixture_id = [7, 8, 9]

    def get_fixture_stats(self):
        for i in self.fixture_id:
            print(i, self.league, self.season)

class SeasonStats(PlayerStats, TeamStats, FixtureStats):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('SeasonStats successfully initiate')

    def __call__(self, called_method, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(PlayerStats, called_method):
            print('True P')
            PlayerStats.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.dispatch_map.get(called_method)()

        elif hasattr(TeamStats, called_method):
            print('True T')
            TeamStats.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.dispatch_map.get(called_method)()

        elif hasattr(FixtureStats, called_method):
            print('True F')
            FixtureStats.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.dispatch_map.get(called_method)()
        else:
            raise(ValueError)

    def call_func(self, func):
        return func

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stats = SeasonStats()
    stats('get_player_stats', 'EN_PR', '2019')
    stats('get_team_stats', 'EN_PR', '2019')
    stats('get_fixture_stats', 'EN_PR', '2019')
```